# Converting .ui to .py with Python 3.10 on PyQt6 - Empty .py file result

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt6

I'm trying to convert an `.ui` files (11kb) to a `.py` files using pyqt6, but in result I get empty py files.

I've used the following command to convert my `files.ui` to `files.py`:

```
python pyuic6 ui_main.ui > ui_main.py
```

It does work as in result a `ui_main.py` is created, but it is empty.

I have tried another command line:

```
python pyuic6 -o ui_main0.py -x ui_main.ui
```

But nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions, please? Thank you

Comment: "It does work" is a bit vague. Do you get any debug? Also, the default positional argument of the `python` command is a script, so, unless you have an *actual* file exactly named `pyuic6` in the current working dir, the above would output anything. Besides, why are you trying to launch the pyuic script like that instead of launching the *actual* script?

Comment: When I say it does work, I mean a file named ui_main.py is created, but an empty one. I have opened a cmd in the working dir to use the command. I launch the pyuic script like this because it's what I've seen online.

Comment: As far as I can remember, the `-x` flag has being ignored since Qt6. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "an empty one"? Is it a **0-size** file? Or your "empty one" means that it does nothing? Because there's a ***huge*** difference between the both. Also, remember that pyuic generated files are not intended to be directly used, as their purpose is to be used as *imports*, as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/designer.html). What you have "seen online" is irrelevant, what *works* and is accepted convention is.

Comment: Yes I know, it is ready to be imported in my main.py. I mean a 0-size file.

Comment: And does removing that `-x` flag change the result in the output file?

Comment: No output file is created when removing that -x

Comment: As said since the beginning, the `pyuic6` argument alone is irrelevant, unless you have a `pyuic6` file (with that specific name as a file, or with a directory named like it with an `__init__.py` file inside) that is part of the python path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Thanks for the help.

```
with open('ui_main.py', 'w') as fout:
    uic.compileUi('ui_main.ui', fout)
```